# If-else using PHP, variable not working as intended

Tags: php, mysql

I am using OSTicket, a ticket support system. Using a dropdown menu in PHP, I would like to make a form which displays either one or two options, depending on the user. A regular user only shows scenario 1. Special users will see scenario 2.

**Scenario 1 for regular users**

```
<select name="filter" class="form-control">
<option value="">Please select</option>
<option value="1">Option 1</option>
```

**Scenario 2 for special users**

```
<select name="filter" class="form-control">
<option value="">Please select</option>
<option value="1">Option 1</option>
<option value="1">Option 2</option>
```

Every user is linked to a organisation in my database. Each organisation has it's own value (org_id). There is a connection to the database and the query is succesful.

In OSTicket, this function exists: `$thisclient->getOrgId`, which I can use to list the org_id for a user. When I echo it (`echo $thisclient->getOrgId;`) I see the org_id from that user, so it does work. But no matter what I try, whenever I enter it into the form, it does not work.

```
<select name="filter" class="form-control">
<option value="">Please select</option>
<option value="1">Option 1</option>
<?php if($thisclient->getOrgId == 3); {echo "<option value=\"2\">Option 2</option>";} ?>
```

If I change the if-statement above to 4, 5, 999, 203232, or whatever: it always seems 'true' so the second option is displayed. I only want to display the second option whenever the value equals a specific value in the database(e.g. 3). I hope someone can help me out.

**Solution**

> getOrgId()

Comment: try removing the `;` after the if statement

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I tried but no difference.

Comment: Then you did it wrong! `if( ... ) ;` <- empty operation. Correct would be: `if ( ... ) action();` or `if ( ... ) { /* code*/ }`

Comment: `getOrdId` is a method, not an attribute. You want `$thisclient->getOrgId()`

Comment: Thank you! I added () to the method and now it's working as intended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code of

```
if($thisclient->getOrgId == 3);
```

contains two problems:

1. The `;` specifies that nothing should be done if the condition is true. You need to remove this.
2. `getOrgId` is a method, you need to call it, like `$thisclient->getOrgId()`